# Issue adding string to List<String>

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to get the mp3 files from the sd card and put them on a listview why does this code not work it messes up when adding elements to the song name

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST };
Cursor tempCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                 proj,
                                 null,
                                 null,
                                 null);
tempCursor.moveToFirst(); //reset the cursor
int col_index=-1;
int numSongs=tempCursor.getCount();
int currentNum=0;
do{
    col_index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);
    List<String> songname = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(tempCursor.moveToNext()){
        songname.add(tempCursor.getString(currentNum+1));
        ArrayAdapter<String> songss = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.songs,songname);
        setListAdapter(songss);
    } else{
        return;
    }
    currentNum++;  
}while (tempCursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: What error does it give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line should be outside of the do...while() loop

```
List<String> songname = new ArrayList<String>();
```

as the loop iterating every time songname will define in memory with new object and you got only last name. simillary this code also after the while loop

```
ArrayAdapter<String> songss = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.songs,songname);
setListAdapter(songss);
```

here is the complete code

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST };
Cursor tempCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                 proj,
                                 null,
                                 null,
                                 null);

int col_index=-1;
int numSongs=tempCursor.getCount();
int currentNum=0;
List<String> songname = new ArrayList<String>();
while (tempCursor.moveToNext())
    col_index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);

    songname.add(tempCursor.getString()); // here you need the column index number of song title name only
}

ArrayAdapter<String> songss = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.songs,songname);
setListAdapter(songss);
```

Comment: Thank you so much man i will try it. yall have been a big help ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code does not make much sense, what are you trying to do?

```
List<String> songNames = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = grabCursorWithSongs();
try {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String songName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("song_name"));
        songNames.add(songName);
    }
} finally {
    c.close();
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(...);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It just force closes when i run.  .... Im trying to make an mp3 player app and this section of the code is suppose to take songs from the sd card and add them to a listview